# R2 of validation sample

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

After removing 25% (21 observations) of the sample as a holdout, model selection on the original 75% of the a sample led to a six variable multiple linear regression with R2 of 54%.

A simple regression of the holdout values on their predictions under the fitted model led to an R2 of 8% and and adjusted R2 of 2%.  Regression slope parameter was non-significant.

Can anyone think of an interpretation other than that there is potentially a serious overfitting issue here, enough that the original six-variable model is in question?  Was there a better way to use the holdout sample to validate the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the incorrect formula for $R^2$ in the holdout sample, as you are allowing a recalibration of the predictions.  Use the formula $R^{2} = 1 - \frac{SSE}{SST}~$  where SSE is the error sum of squares and SST is the total sum of squares ($(n-1)\times~$ sample variance).  You will find that your low $R^2$ wasn't low enough.

Your sample size is too small by a factor of about 240 to be using data splitting as a validation method.  This is highly unstable.  I'm also guessing that you used stepwise variable selection, which will result in inferior predictions.

Comment: The $R^2$ as Excel suggests that when $R^2$ is near 1.0 the fit is a great approximation of the data, and when it is near to 0.0 it is a poor fit.  Is this an Excel-like $R^2$ or something different?

Comment: I would not trust Excel for anything statistical.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The R2 I mentioned was in fact the regression R2, not the Pearson so I think it corresponds to what you are suggesting(?)

Comment: Oops - that last comment was submitted to soon - am learning this text editor.  What I meant is that the quoted R2 was from the ANOVA table =1-SSresid/(SSresid+SSpredicted.values) so appears to be what you are suggesting.  About the the sample size being too small for data splitting - would you know of a reference on this?  I'd be interested in looking it up.  Thanks

Comment: That's still not clear.  If you re-fit a new regression with the predicted values against $Y$ that's wrong.  The only way the above formula is right is if you fixed the intercept at zero and the slope at one.  If you plug in the formula I provided at the top, where SSE is the sum of squared errors without any recalibration with a new slope and intercept, you will be fine.  But you have a huge problem with the woefully inadequate sample size to be doing data splitting.  Split the data again and you'll get a completely different result.  You need a better modeling strategy and use resampling.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. 
`# y.valid are validation sample`
`# y.valid.pred are predicted values in validation sample given fitted model of training data`
`> SSE=sum((y.valid.pred-y.valid)^2)`
`> SST=sum((y.valid-mean(y.valid))^2)`
`> 1-SSE/SST`
`[1] -0.6176578`
I agree there is need for another modeling approach.

Comment: If you sum of squared errors is truly greater than the sum of squares total (which really is possible on holdout samples), this indicates your predictions are much worse than random predictions.  This would point to a deeply flawed model development strategy as well as a woefully inadaquate sample size for data splitting to be valid.

Comment: Thank you.  The original model was obtained by application of a variable selection algorithm on ~50 independent variables each of which had 4 transformations so I suppose it is not surprising.

Comment: Right.  You were effectively fitting as many parameters as you had observations so the result is pure noise.  Note that candidate variables count against you when using variable selection, not just the number of variables selected.